# Fabric js : No group member update while moving

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

My first question here, after years of finding solutions in other's topics !
First, sorry if my english is not perfect !

I'm using Fabric js in my application and I have to implement a button to group texts or images.

However, I noticed that, when I move the group on the canvas, the group coords are updated but not the group's objects'.

On the canvas, objects are moving well with their group, but in the console, it seems that they always have the same 'top' and 'left' values.

Is it a normal groups behaviour, in which case, I really don't understand, or there is something I am missing ?

It can be noted that I added objects in the group with the addWithUpdate(obj) method.

I really hope someone can help me !

Comment: yes this is normal. Individual objects only update when they are removed from the group or you can do some calls to get the resolved final positioning. Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
If objects update when they are removed from the group, I think I'm going to remove them when I need to know their positions !
I'll try this and, if I don't manage to find a solution to my problem, I'll try to ask another, more specific, question !

Thanks again !

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is normal.
However you can find the position without destroying and rebuilding the group in this way:

given a `group` that is a `fabric.Group` and a childObject that is a subclass of `fabric.Object` you can:

1) create a point with childObject top and left

`var point = new fabric.Point(childObject.left, childObject.top);`

2) get the group transformMatrix:

`var transform = group.calcTransformMatrix();`

3) transform the point with this matrix:

`var actualCoordinates = fabric.util.transformPoint(point, transform);`

and you should be set.